# An employee quit without notice the morning after a holiday

Tags: united-states

I had a disgruntled employee quit (before clocking in) the morning after a holiday.  Do I need to pay her for the holiday?  It was not in the employee handbook about working the day before/ day after a holiday - but I fixed it -now it is.

Comment: Presumably, their holiday entitlement and required notice period are in their contract — what does that say? I'm not sure why you think that you _wouldn't_ need to pay someone if they've accrued and taken paid time off?

Answer (score 2):

The honorable thing to do is to keep your promises. You need to honor the contract you had with the employee at the time that they quit. Having expenses is a normal cost of doing business. Imagine if the employee had taken a vacation day (paid day off) and then quit after that. Would you be talking about not paying them for their vacation day? No.